# securely display image from s3 on front end

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an image in my s3 bucket that I wish to display on the front end of my page. I am able to do this by using an `img` tag and having the `src` as the file's public URL - however I'm wondering if this is insecure since it exposes details like the bucket name, key name and file name. Is there a more secure way to do this in such a way that the public URL isn't exposed (and thus nobody can find out details like the bucket name?

Comment: Intentionally providing access to a public object is not 'insecure' since you actually want it to be accessible. Having somebody know the name of the Bucket and the Key of the object does make it 'insecure', since you want it to be public. If you have **private objects** for which you wish to selectively control access, your back-end can create an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object. This is a way to 'securely' provide access to private objects.

Answer (score 0):

An image could be displayed based on its content and not URL.

1. Get content of the image and make it base64, something like:

   `$img = base64_encode($imageContent);`
2. Show image with help of this base64 content, sample code:

   `<img src="data:image/png;base64,$img" />`

Please note that `png` in this part of code is the `mime type` of the
image: `src="data:image/png`.

Answer (score -3):

This blog gives a good description: https://aws.plainenglish.io/using-node-js-to-display-images-in-a-private-aws-s3-bucket-4c043ed5c5d0